# Not able to access a variable from code behind in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have declared a variable in code behind 
the variable name is  progressbar which is of int type

to access this variable in the same asp.net page i am using this code

```
 <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" frame="border" 
        style="border-color: #FF0000" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FF0066" colspan="0" rowspan="0" width="<%= progressbar %>%">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="0" rowspan="0">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

i have used both `<%= progressbar %>` and `<%# progressbar %>` but not able to access this variable.
Can you tell me how can I access this variable from c# code behind to the asp.net page

Comment: You'll get a more accurate answer if you post the code-behind code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables in C# are local variables, and they're only visible inside the function they were declared in. Make your thing a field or a property instead, and make sure it's either `protected` or `public`.

Comment: Surely you know how to declare a field or a property without an example? If you don't, I suggest you read a tutorial that explains the basics of C#.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure the variable you're trying to access is not private
2. You should be able to accesss it like this `<%= progressbar %>`

within the class write

```
public int progressbar = 0;
```